# Hashtable with free size key value using mmap

Tags: c, hashtable, key-value, mmap

I'm currently working on a hashtable on disk implementation in C.

After reading code on few packages, i know about using `mmap` would give better performance than `fwrite`, but on those packages, they have fixed key/value size like this:

```
size_t data_size = sizeof(Header) + table_index_size() + total_entries * key_value_size();
ftruncate(f, data_size);
mmap(NULL, data_size, prot, MAP_SHARED, file, 0);
```

So, the table has equal entry size which can be calculate the total size from the beginning.

What if i want to have free size key/value?

About the key size, i supposed the solution is to use hashing algo like `md5/murmur` to convert key to fixed length `uint64_t` number, but i have no idea about the value.

On some answers about increasing mmap size is using `ftruncate`, `munmap` and `mmap` again to change file size after the recalculation, but i'm not sure would it thread-safe or reduce the insert performance?